# Can't get value of input inside form on Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple form in the html page. Now, this is an "Add-Edit" form, so when i open the page with an ID i should compile all the inputs with the ObjectId values, when i open the page without Id i should be able to compile all the inputs manually and then add the object to the database. The problem is that i can't read/write the value of the inputs field using:

```
this.form.get["inputName"].setValue(value);
```

the console show:

```
 Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
```

This is the html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()" #formDir="ngForm" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" (dateInput)="addEvent($event)" (dateChange)="addEvent($event)" formControlName="picker">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label class=" control-label col-md-3">cost</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="cost">
    </div>

    <label for="vehicles">Veicoli</label>
    <select formControlName="vehicleList" id="vehicleList">
      <option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles; let i = index" [value]="vehicles[i].id">
        {{vehicles[i].plate}}
      </option>
    </select>

    <label class=" control-label col-md-3">startKm</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="startKm">
    </div>

    <label class=" control-label col-md-3">endKm</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="endKm">
    </div>

    <label class=" control-label col-md-3">liter</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="liter">
    </div>

    <label class=" control-label col-md-3">average</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="average">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary float-left" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FuelService } from '../services/fuel.service';
import { VehiclesService } from '../services/vehicles.service';
import { Fuel } from '../models/fuel';
import { Vehicle } from '../models/vehicle';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fuel-add-edit',
  templateUrl: './fuel-add-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fuel-add-edit.component.css']
})
export class FuelAddEditComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  plateCtrl: FormControl;
  actionType: string;
  fuelId: number;
  errorMessage: any;
  existingFuel: Fuel;
  vehicles: Vehicle[];
  dataSelected: Date;

  constructor(private fuelService: FuelService, private vehicleService: VehiclesService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private avRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    const idParam = 'id';
    this.actionType = 'Add';
    if (this.avRoute.snapshot.params[idParam]) {
      this.fuelId = this.avRoute.snapshot.params[idParam];
    }

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        picker: [''],
        cost: ['', [Validators.required]],
        vehicleList: [''],
        startKm: ['', [Validators.required]],
        endKm: ['', [Validators.required]],
        liter: ['', [Validators.required]],
        average: ['', [Validators.required]]
      }
    )

    of(this.vehicleService.getVehicles().subscribe(data=> (
      this.vehicles = data
    )))

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.fuelId > 0) {
      console.log(this.form);
      this.actionType = "Edit";
      this.fuelService.getFuel(this.fuelId)
        .subscribe(data => (
          this.existingFuel = data,
          this.form.get["picker"].setValue(data.date),
          this.form.get["cost"].setValue(data.cost),
          this.form.get["vehicleList"].setValue(data.vehicle.id),
          this.form.get["startKm"].setValue(data.startKm),
          this.form.get["endKm"].setValue(data.endKm),
          this.form.get["liter"].setValue(data.liter),
          this.form.get["average"].setValue(data.average)
        ));
    }
  }

  get picker() { return this.form.get("picker"); }
  get cost() { return this.form.get("cost"); }
  get vehicleList() { return this.form.get("vehicleList"); }
  get startKm() { return this.form.get("startKm"); }
  get endKm() { return this.form.get("endKm"); }
  get liter() { return this.form.get("liter"); }
  get average() { return this.form.get("average"); }
}
```

Comment: There is no `get` property which is an array in the  `formGroup` object. Perhaps you were looking for `this.form.get("inputName").setValue(value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not:

```
this.form.get["inputName"].setValue(value);
```

It's:

```
this.form.get('inputName').setValue(value);
```

The `get()` method gives you access to control in the form group. It is not an object to access the property via square brackets.

Comment: @Nicolas I changed it to object only. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, i solved. That was so dumb on my end, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use patchValue to change a specific value like below, or replace it with setValue if you wan't to change all values in the form.

```
this.form.patchValue({
    inputName: value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this get is only to get the field, if you want to read:

```
 this.form.value.inputName;
```

if you want to write one element in the form use patchValue

```
      this.form.patchValue({ inputName: value });
```